# IntelliJ not recognizing classes within the same package - however the program compiles and runs fine

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-package

Here's the scene: [image]

For some reason, IntelliJ doesn't accept that Util.java or GraphEdge.java are in the MyHelper package. Therefore, method completion doesn't work. This also causes issues in the main program I'm working on - which will use this package as a jar.

As you can see by the output, this still compiles and runs fine. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any such package.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Ok, I got it. I guess I have to create a package... for some reason just writing "package xxx;" at the top of the file doesn't cut it. Thanks for pointing this out